# Number of packets in broadcast/multicast

Tags: broadcast, dhcp

When a host sends out a broadcast, how does it calculate the number of packets (same) that it needs to send out so that all the other hosts on the same LAN would receive it? For example, when a host boots up, it sends a DHCP broadcast to all the other hosts in the LAN. How can it determine the number of packets (same) to send?

Comment: It was my understanding that a host sends out a single packet, addressed to .255; it's the other hosts' responsibilty to know receive those packets destined for .255... can't comment on multicast.

Comment: But lets say there are 5 hosts, than would each host read the same packet and forward it sequentially to other hosts or there would be 5 copies of the same packet sent by the original host?

Comment: I'm assuming you're talking about broadcast. Each host will read the same packet. Because it is a broadcast packet, switches will route it to every single node, so there's no reason to need to forward it... it's already been sent out, and every host on that subnet is going to see it.

Comment: Fair warning, it's possible that this question may get closed based on the fact that it's less of a discussion of programming, and more of a discussion on how ip networks work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, double checked with wikipedia. You mention both "broadcast/multicast" in your title, but they're significantly different from each other.

There is no calculation for broadcast. The answer is, you don't know, or care, how many other hosts are out there. You send a single packet to the broadcast address, and it's the responsibility of every host listening to act on the packet that was sent. On a Class C subnet, such as a 192.168.x.x, the broadcast address is 192.168.x.255.

With multicast, the originating host still only needs to send out one packet, so again, no calculation of total packets is needed. From wikipedia:

> Multicast uses network infrastructure efficiently by requiring the
>   source to send a packet only once, even if it needs to be delivered to
>   a large number of receivers. The nodes in the network take care of
>   replicating the packet to reach multiple receivers only when
>   necessary.